# NoClassDeffoundError nineoldAndroid

Tags: android, nineoldandroids

I want to use nineOldAndroid to my project. I have downloaded the project and import the library and works fine. Now I have add the library to my project but I have this error.

```
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.animation.ObjectAnimator
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at my.package.es.MainFragment$1.onClick(MainFragment.java:105)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2501)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9107)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
06-17 18:26:33.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In the line of the error I have this code:

```
button_my.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(miscrol, "scrollY", 0, 480).setDuration(3000);
                    objectAnimator.start();

                }
            });


06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at com.nineoldandroids.util.IntProperty.set(IntProperty.java:43)
06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at com.nineoldandroids.util.IntProperty.set(IntProperty.java:43)
06-17 18:46:59.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at com.nineoldandroids.util.IntProperty.set(IntProperty.java:43)
```

and my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofInt(miscrol, "scrollY", 0, 480).setDuration(3000);
                    objectAnimator.start();

                }
```

Comment: Did you found answer to your updated issue??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your imports.

You're using Android's `ObjectAnimator`, which is not available for your API level. NineOldAndroids has its own (`com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator`).

Answer (score 2):

I am satisfied with HelloWorld's answer but I would like to show the full dependency!.

```
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
I needed to add that dependancy too 
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'